# Notification Sound stops when opening Notification Panel

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am working over a project and i am facing a strange problem in notification.
Basically i want to play alarm in notification and for that i am adding sound i.e.uri in Notification Builder.
Here is my code:

```
builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon).setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(msg)
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white))
            .addAction(R.drawable.alarm_off, getString(R.string.dismiss), pendingIntent)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setSound(Uri.parse(path));

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(WAKE_UP_ALARM_ID, notification);
```

Notification appears in panel but when i touched the notification panel to scroll down, music stops automatically.
I am unable to understand the scenario.

Please help me to sort out the problem.

Thanks

Comment: that is the default behavior of android system

Comment: but when alarm plays on android android lollipop it's playing continuously.

Comment: well I don't know what happen in alarm but I pretty sure that the alarm is not notification even flag FLAG_INSISTENT in the doc you will find that when user open notification menu the sound will stop

Comment: hmm.. in that case i should do sound handling  in service and once user click the notification i'll stop that

Comment: exactly and make sure in your activity oncreate() you differentiate between if your activity start due to notification click or opened normally

Comment: I have to use service and broadcast receiver to tackle this issue.

Comment: in all cases you have to stop service when activity open due to notification click

Comment: @AnkurChaudhary Hi, I'm facing the same issue. So there is no other option for how to play notification sound if the user opens the notification panel? I have to use service right? (I'm using it for incoming VoIP call notification).

Answer (score 0):

> **The flags that are used in notification builder**
>
> 1.Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND:used to play sound.
>
> 2.Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT:this flag is makes your sound to ring continuously until you have done few operations on notification ie,
>   either you drag the bar or you click the bar.
>
> 3.Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL:this flag is used to automatically cancel the notification after you have seen it

Comment: What you are trying to say?

Comment: What actually you want ? U want to play notification sound until the user swipe or touch the notification bar right ?

Comment: Not the notification bar. It should stop when user clicks on our notification action button.

Comment: i have check this. This post is to cancel a notification. I want to let the music play until user click on action button. While the problem i am facing is that it stop when i open the notification panel.

Comment: Their should be a flag.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_INSISTENT

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Have you got any workaround

Comment: @Jyoti Did you solved this issue? Did you use the service?

Comment: @PepaZapletal This was default behaviour of android and we have no solution yet.